# python: format of float numbers

Tags: python, floating-point

I am working on the python script that save coordinates of a point (representing geometrical center of a 3D structure) in multi-model file (result.pdb) contained 240 models of the same atom with 240 different coordinates (XYZ) separated by ENDMDL term. Here is a fragment of my python script:

```
# this function calculates XYZ of the given atomic coordinates
def lig_center(nested_array_list):
    a = numpy.array(nested_array_list)
    mean = numpy.mean(a, axis=0)
    return mean[0], mean[1], mean[2]  # x, y, z


# make the list of the centres for each of the conformation
conf_xyz=[]
i=1
# loop each of the 240 conformations
for conf in d.ch.conformations:
    number=i
    # get XYZ of all atoms of each conformations
    xyz=conf.getCoords()
    # get XYZ of the geometrical center of these coordinates
    col=lig_center(xyz)
    # store geometrical center as in a list
    col1 = list(col)
    # append it to the existing list called conf_xyz
    conf_xyz.append(col1)
    # store coordinates of the centers in the output pdb file:
    with open(outputfilename+".pdb", "a") as f:
    # for each of the model first print its index
        print >>f, 'MODEL'+str(i)
    # then print the name of the atom (always C and its XYZ taken from the list col:
        print >>f, 'ATOM      1  C   COM     1      '+'%.2f  %.2f  %.2f' %(col[0],col[1],col[2])+' 1.00 0.00'
        print >>f, 'ENDMDL'
    i=i+1
```

The problem of this method in the output format. Here is what I have in the result.pdb output file:

```
MODEL79
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      22.06  -14.69  6.02 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL80
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      20.01  -17.91  4.69 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL81
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      04.38  -9.05  -7.02 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL82
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      3.12  -3.63  -9.41 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL83
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      4.13  -6.49  -7.51 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL84
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      3.22  -3.67  -9.70 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL85
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      4.22  -4.74  -8.54 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL86
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      1.70  -2.19  -12.49 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL87
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      3.32  -3.98  -10.74 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
```

And here is what I should have instead:

```
MODEL79
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      22.06  -14.69  06.02 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL80
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      20.01  -17.91  04.69 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL81
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      04.38  -09.05  -07.02 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL82
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      03.12  -03.63  -09.41 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL83
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      04.13  -06.49  -07.51 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL84
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      03.22  -03.67  -09.70 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL85
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      04.22  -04.74  -08.54 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL86
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      01.70  -02.19  -12.49 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL87
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      03.32  -03.98  -10.74 1.00 0.00
```

Note in the second case, the XYZ (6-8) columns are perfectly aligned because of the xx.xx format of each value ( I added ZERO to x.xx, like convertion of 4.22  -4.74  -8.54 to 04.22  -04.74  -08.54 etc).

supposing that the format of the output file is defined in the end of my python script, via

```
print >>f, 'ATOM      1  C   COM     1      '+'%.2f  %.2f  %.2f' %(col[0],col[1],col[2])+' 1.00 0.00'
```

one of the solution is to replace it with

```
 print >>f, 'ATOM      1  C   COM     1      '+'%05.2f  %05.2f  %05.2f' %(col_B[0],col_B[1],col_B[2])+' 1.00 0.00'
```

which does the correct job for positive numbers but does nothing with negative ones:

```
MODEL7 
ATOM 1 C COM 1 06.09 -19.59 -0.90 1.00 0.00 
ENDMDL 
MODEL8 
ATOM 1 C COM 1 06.51 -19.86 -1.27 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
```

Comment: Probably `%05.2f`. The [`%` formatting operator](https://stackabuse.com/python-string-interpolation-with-the-percent-operator/) follows the [c `printf` convention](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm).

Comment: i've tried it, it added indeed 0 to all positive numbers X.XX but not to the negative ones: MODEL7
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      06.09  -19.59  -0.90 1.00 0.00
ENDMDL
MODEL8
ATOM      1  C   COM     1      06.51  -19.86  -1.27 1.00 0.00

Comment: The format isn't that flexible. The `5` means that there needs to be at least 5 characters. So, for negative numbers, the `-` eats one character.

Comment: yes correct. one question how would it be possible to add 2 zeros ? e.g to convert 1.00 20.00 100.00 to 001.00 020.00 100.00 ? Note that it should not change format of the number which already has the format: XXX.XX

Comment: For that it would be `%06.2f`. Use leading zeroes, 6 characters, with 2 being decimals.

Comment: OK, I gotcha! Thank you again! this time it adds 00 zeros to the positive numbers and one zero to negative :-)

Comment: For alignment of the sign, put a space after the "%":  `'% 07.2f' % number` will consistently give the format "sDDD.DD", where the "D"s are digits and the "s" is a sign - either "-" or " ".